# why Mysql Rand() has a different behaviour while using left join

Tags: mysql, random

I'm trying to implement some fuzziness thing in a mysql (v5.7 on Mac & Linux) query but realized mysql `Rand()` has a weird behaviour while using/not using a left join with an empty table!

To reproduce this I made 2 tables, t1 with 1000 records and t2 with no record.
Then I tried to run these 2 queries:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE RAND() < 0.5;
SELECT count(*) FROM t1 WHERE RAND() < 0.5;
```

The **first** query returns ~250 records but the **second** one returns ~500.

Couldn't find any explanation about this.
Any idea would be helpful

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=387788c2e6032563ef6861c2104445fd Does  it happen every single time for you?

Comment: How do you count the records?

Comment: @GarethD it happens every time, I also attached a screenshot to the question. Not sure why it's working fine in dbfiddle. I also tried the same queries on production, same result.

Comment: @stickybit added screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Also faced the same issue on the production. (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cce1976b3a98982fe002727fa994902d)

So, what I found. It is reproducible with:

1. Mysql version 5.*. (It's fixed on the 8).
2. Happens on the **LEFT JOIN** only
3. It is reproducible with **`id int auto_increment primary key`** on the joinable table.
4. Join must contain **no intersection**.

As a result - **RAND()** chance was applied twice.

As a solution: use `WHERE T1.ID NOT IN (SELECT ...)`. It will run join in the sub-query that doesn't affect the main.